# How do you trace incoming/outgoing HTTP connections on a rooted Android?

Tags: firewall

I would like to get a trace of any incoming & outgoing requests over HTTP from my android phone over a period of time (like you can do with Fiddler on a PC) - is there tool apart from WhisperCore that can do something like this?

The reason i don't want WhisperCore is because it needs to encrypt your whole device before it lets you use the tracer

Comment: try tcpdump, netstat combination.

Comment: It probably depends on what specifically you're trying to achieve.  Are you trying to trace what calls an application is making, or just what the browser is doing?  Is the device rooted?

Comment: You could use your computer to host a wireless connection, and proxy through Fiddler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shark/Sharkreader in market (tcpdump frontend)